# X and Y are sets of sentences. If X is a subset of Y then Model(Y) is a subset of Model (X)

Tags: logic

How do we show that for any sets sentences X and Y, and any sentences a and b, if X is a subset of Y then Model(Y) is a subset of Model (X)?

Also, how to show that X union {a} is a tautological consequence of b if and only if X is a tautological consequence of a implies b?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: The second paragraph should read: "X union {a} *has* tautological consequence b," or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not precisely a **subset**, since the "class" of models of a theory is to large to form a set in the sense of ZFC.

But if we restrict the models under consideration to models whose underlying set is a subset of some **fixed** set $S$, then it is true,

This is because any model of $Y$ is in particular a model of $X$. For let $M$ be a model of $Y$. Then any sentence of $Y$ is true in $M$, and since $X\subseteq Y$, every sentence of $X$ is true in $M$.